# How do I get Chrome App launcher?

Tags: google-chrome

I was reading [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/05/google-chrome-35-linux-arrives-aura) article. I'm a little confused on how to get the Chrome App Launcher. They put a link, but it goes [nowhere](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/launcher). Can anyone help? Or can anyone suggest an app in the Ubuntu software center that would look the same?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about a product that is unavailable for Ubuntu. And replacements are, at the time, non-existing.

Comment: If it can't be done on Ubuntu, that should be the answer. Marking the question as off-topic is wrong IMO. And in fact it can be done on Ubuntu (I'll post the answer when the question is reopened), so I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: proof it can be done: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/notification-center-google-now-cards.html

Comment: Now that chrome's Aura is finally on Linux, this question is not off-topic!!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the [Chrome App Launcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/launcher) is not available for Linux.

For an alternative, you can simply use the Unity Dash which is also capable of launching Chrome apps directly.

[reference](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/v94iqGQdgI8)

it is now available: http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.nl/2014/07/stable-channel-update.html